# Как сделать нумерацию с 8 утра. Новый день - новая нумерация

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Я делаю свой первый сайт для мед.клиники. В Бишкеке.

Дело в том что клиентам при открытии наряда на прием к врачу присваиваются id-номера из phpMyAdmin. Ну там пришел к примеру Васечкин Иван Петрович в 8-23 утра, а ему в базе Регистратора присваиваться порядковый номер 134, хотя он первый с утра.

Как сделать чтобы у него был первый номер за этот день автоматически? И как это привязать к местному времени?!

P.S. Само собой разумеется у него будет оригинальный ID - 134, и номер - 1 за этот день. В таблицах, в браузере надо отображать 1.

Comment: Сделать поле без автоинкремента?

Comment: Из phpMyAdmin? Может из mysql?

Comment: ну так...эм..... у вас же наверняка должно быть поле дата... datetime например..... вы когда выбираете людей, выбираете их за сегодняшний день с сортировкой ASC по полю date.... а в php выводите по порядку просто

Comment: сделайте таблицу для регистрации с полями datetime и id пользователя и дальше как написано [выше](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596823/#comment805581_596823).

Comment: пример таблицы: id, user_id, doctor_id, date_reception(тип datetime)

Comment: Столько ответов и все неправильные! :-)
Объясню суть:

id-autoincrement наряда мне нужен. он завязан на многие таблицы.
Внутри наряда (пример: лечение зубов в доктора Зайцевой В.А.) будет 3 визита
 (1-удаление правого верхнего резца, 2- удаление нижнего второго клыка и 3 - лечение переднего 
 зуба).
 Даты этих визитов ставятся автоматом.
 Теперь нужно придумать как ставить нумерацию нарядов разным клиентам с утра по порядку.

Comment: Есть ли возможность выбора времени приема. Если да, то скажем кто то записался на 9 ему дали номер 1, потом кто то записался на 13 часов, ему дали номер 2 т.к. он записывался вторым. тут пришел третий и записался на 12. ему давать номер 3 ? т.е. номера не обязаны быть подряд по вермени. А если кто то записался и отменил запись, что с его номером происходит ?

Comment: У каждого наряда или внутреннего визита есть свой datetime и id. А порядковые номера нарядов и визитов  с утра должны даваться автоматически. Кто пришел первым на регистратуру - тот получает 1 номер, кто пришел вторым - у того наряд под номером 2 и т.д.

Comment: А если кто то получил номер 3 и позвонил отменил запись. (на момент отмены больше не было записи после него) то следующий пришедший получит его номер 3 или уже 4 (вдруг тот с талончиком 3 вернется). Т. е. достаточно ли брать максимальный номер за этот день плюс 1 или же надо в отдельной таблице фиксировать последний использованный, даже если его уже нет

Comment: Порядковые номера получают те клиенты, кто сам пришел на регистратуру и отметился у нее лично. Запись к доктору не имеет к этой нумереции никакого отношения. Пришел - получил порядковый номер, не пришел - нет номера.

Answer (score 2):

Вставляйте новые записи в таблицу следующим запросом:

```
insert into Table(day_num, col1, col2, ...)
 select coalesce(max(day_num),0)+1, 'xxx', 'yyy', ...
   from Table
  where dt >= curdate()+interval 8 hour
    and dt < curdate()+interval 32 hour
```

Вместо `curdate()` можно использовать другую дату (без времени), на которую происходит запись.

Comment: "day_num + 1" -можно конечно найти в базе. Но как порядковый номер обнулять каждый день, к примеру в 7 ч. утра?! Автоматом! И второй вопрос: как потом различать между собой первый номер от 28 ноября и первый номер от 27 ноября?

Comment: Mike, там получается будет двойная нумерация. Первая id-autoincrement - невидимая в браузере и нумерация порядковая с утра начиная с нуля (которая должна сама, автоматом ставиться с цифры 1). Как это сделать?

Comment: @aiba А его не надо обнулять. присмотритесь к запросу. Он выбирает максимальный номер за текущий день. На следующий день он автоматом начнет записи с 1, потому как записей с 8 утра _текущего_ дня в БД еще не будет, max() вернет за этот день NULL, coalesce превратит его в 0. Как отличать - видимо эти два поля day_num и дату всегда показывать на экране или в талонах или еще где вместе

Comment: @aiba Вы же сами сказали, что у в вас будет еще и обычный ID, так и делайте его, как обычный ID, с auto_increment, В запросе он разумеется не участвует, т.к. создается автоматически самой БД

Answer (score 2):

**Код писать не хочу, просто подкину идейку...**
У вас по сути уже все необходимое в наличии в БД!! Вы хотите что-то куда-то записывать, чтобы наглядно видеть эту ежедневную таблицу ваших номеров регистрации, но ведь нужно совсем другое - отображать в браузере и выдавать номер клиенту!! В этом ваша ошибка.
Так как идею отдаю задаром, просьба полностью исключить ругань и споры по поводу этой идеи!
**Теперь моя идея (в расчете на то, что у автора  автоинкремент!!!):**
1. Получаем вчерашнюю дату (сегодняшняя минус сутки).
2. Запрашиваем в БД максимальный **АВТО**инкремент в диапазоне 1990год - вчерашняя дата))), т.е. максимальный на вчерашний вечер **АВТО**инкремент- это будет наше волшебное число.
3. После создания новой записи получаем её **АВТО**инкремент и вычитаем из него волшебное число.
4. SIC!!! Это и есть сегодняшний номер регистрации, начинающийся с 1 !!!
Все это можно сделать одним запросом!
**Спасибо за внимание!**

Comment: При одновременных транзакциях будет возможность выдать одновременно два одинаковых номера.

Comment: добавил для вас жирный текст!

Comment: Хм.. Кажется, невнимательно читаю. В таком случае, автоинкремент не гарантирует последовательные значения - в случае отката будут дырки. Впрочем, думаю, автора такой вариант устроит.

Comment: в случае отката? тоже поправимо. но думаю вряд ли будут пропуски, так судя по тексту, наряды создает ОДИН оператор или вернее сказать  наряды создаются с одной точки, так что пропуски исключены на человеческом уровне. с другой стороны, пропуски тоже нужны, ибо что такое откат? - пришел чел, получил номер, за ним еще пришло два дедульки, получили следующие номера, первый чел откатился  И ЧТО? следующий пришедший получит ЕГО номер? НЕ!!! так не пойдет, те два дедульки его заклюют! так что исходя из логики процесса, пропуски допустимы и как раз заполнение пропусков в ряду недопустимо!!!.

Comment: Я имел в виду пропуски последних чисел. Я пришёл первым, стал заказывать, потом думаю "тьфу, не тот раздел", жму отмена, потом всё-таки решаю, что раздел был верным, и получаю номер 2 :)

Comment: какой ТЬФУ??? автор пишет что все происходит на стойке регистрации... так что такие метания исключены... чтобы исключить такие метания программно, нужно усложнять, для данной задачи это ни к чему. чо-то я с вами в такие дебри удалился, сорри, больше не комментю!

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за участие и помощь, но мне удалось убедить заказчицу что без оригинального ID - номера каждого наряда не обойтись, того самого, который дается автоматически базой! Т.к. наряды длятся по 2-3 недели (в нем несколько визитов), то будет чехарда с порядковыми номерами, если они будут каждый день с 1 начинаться! А то получится что с утра у многих пациентов одинаковые 1 и 2, хотя они пришли в разное время! Еще раз всем спасибо за помощь!